# LARAVEL 4 solution dynamic SEO URLs wanted

Tags: php, url, routes, seo, laravel-4

I have made pages with **Laravel** and I route them with a nice URL But I'm developing a **real estate website** and I want to have the following URL for a page that shows info of one house: `houseinfo/{town}/{neighborhood}/{street}/{houseID}`

1. My database I have a table **Houses** with records of all houses.
2. Each record has `{town} {neighborhood} {street} and {houseID}` among others

How can I route this page? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
Route::get('/houseinfo/{town}/{neighborhood}/{street}/{houseID}', array(
    'as' => 'houseinfo',
    'uses' => 'HouseController@houseInfo'
));
```

Then, in the HouseController, you can add method with this parameters:

```
public function houseInfo($town, $neighborhood, $street, $houseID){
    // get the data from the model
}
```